# Navigation Fragment <include> Override the startDestination Value

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

i create multi-module Application and implement the navigation component. I have 2 navigation graph for `:app` and `:features:transfer` module.

Below is my `:app`'s navigation graph:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_transfer" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.fanjavaid.navigationcomponent.fragments.MainFragment"
        android:label="Home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_transferNavigationGraph"
            app:destination="@id/transferNavigationGraph" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_balanceFragment"
            app:destination="@id/balanceFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/balanceFragment"
        android:name="com.fanjavaid.navigationcomponent.fragments.BalanceFragment"
        android:label="View Balance"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_balance" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_to_mainFragment"
        app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/mainFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</navigation>
```

As you can see, I include the `:features:transfer`'s navigation graph there. However, when i run the App, the `startDestination` that should be `@id/mainFragment` is replaced with `:features:transfer`'s `startDestination`.

Below is `:features:transfer`'s navigation graph:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/transferNavigationGraph"
    app:startDestination="@id/transferRecipientFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/transferRecipientFragment"
        android:name="com.fanjavaid.transfer.fragments.TransferRecipientFragment"
        android:label="Transfer Recipient"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_transfer_recipient">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_transferRecipientFragment_to_transferAmountFragment"
            app:destination="@id/transferAmountFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/transferAmountFragment"
        android:name="com.fanjavaid.transfer.fragments.TransferAmountFragment"
        android:label="Transfer Amount"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_transfer_amount">
        <argument
            android:name="recipient"
            app:argType="com.fanjavaid.data.models.Recipient" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Any idea about this? Maybe I have incorrect implementation.

Thank you

Comment: That's not how `<include>` tags work. There's, in fact, no way for navigation to change the IDs from exactly what you've written. If you add logging to a [listener for navigation events](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events), what are the order of destinations you see printed there?

Comment: It just showing 1 destination: `Destination(com.fanjavaid.navigationcomponent:id/transferAmountFragment) label=Transfer Amount class=com.fanjavaid.transfer.fragments.TransferAmountFragment` because the issue is when first launch the App.

Comment: That isn't even the start destination of your included graph.